# Is it possible to retrieve fields from SOQL in a simpler way?

Tags: soql, rest-api, rest, fields

I'm working with REST API, using endpoint `/services/data/v53.0/query`.
The question in place is: is it possible to retrieve requested fields API names present in SOQL?

Example. Get from `SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name, StageName FROM Opportunities) FROM Account` this data: `Id, Name, Opportunities; Opportunity: Id, Name, StageName`.

How did I solve this problem:

- Retrieve everything that is placed between `SELECT` and `FROM` that aren't in brackets `(...)`, split by `,`.
- Go through resulted List, if there are no brackets `(...)`, than it is a field API name, if there are brackets, then retrieve child relation API name, and recursively retrieve fields API names related to that object (can get its API name with callout to `/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/Account/describe` -> `childRelationships` (match `relationshipName` with `childSObject`)).

Downside for it: if requested `FIELDS(ALL)`, I cannot do such a thing and I need to go through `/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/Account/describe` -> `fields`.

Also I was thinking about just querying `SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name, StageName FROM Opportunities) FROM Account LIMIT 1`, but in case with no records present, that will be just empty response and no API fields names in it: `{"totalSize":0,"done":true,"records":[]}`.

UPDATE for comment (regarding external libraries): we are using php opensource project for it, but it seems to not work properly. If no solution with REST API will be found, we'll probably just fork the repository and correct mistakes in code.

**The question is: am I doing it the only possible way? Is it a simpler approach to get the result?**

Comment: Couldn't you just go through the returned lines and get the api names from there?

Comment: @Damecek This is the exact thing I tried too, I cannot retrieve fields if there is NO account record in organization at a time of request. This is present in the question > Also I was thinking about just querying SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name, StageName FROM Opportunities) FROM Account LIMIT 1, but in case with no records present, that will be just empty response and no API fields names in it.

Comment: The response will be `{"totalSize":0,"done":true,"records":[]}` with no fields.

Comment: You can try a SOQL parser such as [this one](https://github.com/paustint/soql-parser-js) via a roundtrip to JS.

Comment: Yeah, we have tried similar one for the php and it has problems with parsing queries with subqueries in WHERE part, but I guess, it's the only possible way now.

Comment: The particular parser we linked works with subqueries - they have a live site you can test with.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it, worth trying!